# How to round time as per one fixed value in PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to round the hour and minute value if second value is greater than 30 second using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$today = date("H:i:s");
echo $today;//17:59:45
?>
```

Here second value is `45` so my requirement is if second value will be more than `30` then it will be round up means the output should be `18:00` and if second value is less than `30` then it will be `17:59` using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same general principle as "round to {x} decimals in JavaScript" - divide the raw timestamp by 60, round it, multiply by 60 again:

```
echo date('H:i:s', round(time() / 60) * 60);
```